# How to factorise quadratic equation in the form of $x^2+6xy+y^2$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quadratics

My Text book has some questions of quadratic equations in the form of

$x^2+xy+y^2$

1)Is there any strategy or proper way to factorise quadratic equations in such way?
2)Is that a type of quadratic trinomials?if yes why?

Comment: What is the equation you want to solve? Where do $x$ and $y$ live?

Comment: 8x^2+6xy+y^2   I meant factorise

Comment: Do you know how to factor expressions of the form $ax^2 + bx + c$?

Comment: $$
8x^2 + 6xy + y^2 = (2x+y)(4x+y)
$$

Comment: YES I do know that

Comment: dxiv 
Could u do that in the answer field please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $z = \frac{x}{y}$ then $a x^2+b xy+c y^2=y^2(a z^2+b z+c)$. The latter is a quadratic in $z$. Factoring it, then substituting $\frac{x}{y}$ back gives the factorization in terms of $x,y$.

---

[ EDIT ] Here is the fully worked out example for factoring $8x^2+6xy+y^2$.

- Let $z=\frac{x}{y}$ then write $8x^2+6xy+y^2 = y^2(8 z^2 + 6 z + 1)$.
- Factor $8 z^2 + 6 z + 1$ (either by inspection, or) by actually calculating its roots using the quadratic formula:
  $$z_{1,2} = \frac{-6 \pm \sqrt{6^2 - 4 \cdot 8}}{16}= \frac{-6 \pm 2}{16} = \frac{-3 \pm 1}{8}$$
  so $z_1 = -\frac{1}{2}$, $z_2=-\frac{1}{4}$
- It follows that $8 z^2 + 6 z + 1 = 8(z-z_1)(z-z_2) = 8(z+\frac{1}{2})(z+\frac{1}{4})=(2 z+1)(4 z+1)$
- Substituting back $z=\frac{x}{y}$:

$$y^2(8 z^2 + 6 z + 1)=y^2(2 \frac{x}{y}+1)(4 \frac{x}{y}+1)=(2x+y)(4x+y)$$

Comment: Another way to think about this nice (accepted) hint is to suggest that you are looking for factors like $(Rx + Sy)$ instead of factors of the form $(Rx+S)$. That's more symmetrical than "dividing by $y$" and gives you the final answer in the right form. But it is a little less elementary.

Comment: If I gave u an example could you do it for me in your method so i can make sure I had got your point?                           One example is $8x^2+6xy+y^2

Comment: @EthanBolker You are right from a pure math standpoint, of course. The way hinted here only makes it more easily recognizable as a quadratic to factorize. And, in cases a "nice" factorization doesn't exist, it makes it easier to think at the quadratic formula in order to get the "ugly" roots.

Comment: Yes I got the point that helped a lot

Comment: But dxiv the point here how am I going to factorise                                              if you could show me with this example

Comment: But dxiv the point here how am I going to factorise if you could show me with this example     8x^2+6xy+y^2

Comment: @user36312 Edited into the answer.

Comment: Yeah thanks alot

Comment: Dxiv why did you multiply 8 by (z+1/2)??

Comment: For any quadratic: $a z^2 + b z + c = a(z-z_1)(z-z_2)$ where $z_{1,2}$ are its roots. This follows from the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) and generalizes to polynomials of degree $n \gt 2$. It is equivalent to [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Proof).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a strategy. We can use Eisenstein's criterion to show that $x^2+xy+y^2\in K[x,y]=K[x][y]$ is irreducible, hence does not factorize. 
We see, that also
$$
x^2+6xy+y^2
$$
does not factorize. 
If it is reducible, we may use factoring algorithms for polynomials in $R[y]$ with a principal ideal ring $R=K[x]$, if $K$ is a field. This works perfectly for
$$
8x^2+6xy+y^2=(2x+y)(4x+y).
$$

Comment: Scientist talk here and I am the stranger thanks anyway

Comment: @user36312 You haven't heard of Eisenstein?

Comment: I obviously know Einstein and his E=mc^2 and how this lead to development of nuclear bomb and hi

Comment: It is just i could not get your point by the way I appreciate your great offer

Comment: I mean [Eisenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), not Einstein. Have a look at irreducible polynomials.

Comment: I just couldn't get your point by the way I appreciste your effort

Comment: I will have a look on those polynomials

Comment: LOL I thought you meant Einstein